# Python Kivy keep text updated (refresh)

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have this Kivy code running on Jetson Nano. MLX90614 is a temperature sensor connected to the i2c. Once running, It will show the temperature, but it's not updating/refreshing. How can I make it show the actual temperature constantly?

Here is the code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

import board
import busio as io
import adafruit_mlx90614

i2c = io.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA, frequency=100000)
mlx = adafruit_mlx90614.MLX90614(i2c)




class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        label = Label(text='This is the temperature: ' + str(mlx.object_temperature),
                      size_hint=(.5, .5),
                      pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5})

        return label

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

Here is the result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.label = Label(text='This is the temperature: ' + str(mlx.object_temperature),
                          size_hint=(.5, .5),
                          pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5})
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_label, 0)

        return self.label
    
    def update_label(self, dt):
        self.label.text = "This is the temperature: {}".format(mlx.object_temperature)
```